# Can a function call itself?

Tags: python

```
def a():
    #function
    if "b" in c:
        a()
    else:
        #proceed
```

Can I do that?

Comment: what happened when you tried?

Comment: That's [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) which is possible.

Comment: Yes, you can. Additional info: there is no such thing as private function in Python. What you are asking for is called recursion.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do it. That's gonna be a recursive function. An example:

```
def pow(x, n):
    if n == 0: #this if makes the function stop calling itself
       return 1
    else:
       return x * pow(x, n-1)

print(pow(2, 3))
>>> 8
```

Recursion is a way of programming or coding a problem, in which a function calls itself one or more times in its body. Usually, it is returning the return value of this function call. If a function definition fulfills the condition of recursion, we call this function a recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. It is called a recursive function. For example consider the following program.

```
def a(num):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        print(num)
    else:
        num+= 1
        a(num)
```

The `a(num)` function takes in an integer. If it is divisible by two, it prints the value, otherwise increments the variable `num` and calls itself with the new input.

```
>>> a(3)
4
>>> a(5)
6
>>> a(6)
6
```

Answer (score -7):

of cause you can, that is recursion function,for example(delete a directory, including subdirectories and files):

```
def removeDir(dirPath):
    if not os.path.isdir(dirPath):
        return
    files = os.listdir(dirPath)
    try:
        for file in files:
            filePath = os.path.join(dirPath, file)
            if os.path.isfile(filePath):
                os.remove(filePath)
            elif os.path.isdir(filePath):
                removeDir(filePath)
        os.rmdir(dirPath)
    except Exception, e:
        print e
```

Comment: For someone who doesn't know anything about recursion, this will be difficult to understand. Maybe you should give an easier example.

Comment: But I really think it is already a very simple example.@VincentBeltman

Comment: I'm sorry but it is deffinitly not. Take a look at the other answers. They are simple, easy to understand and don't need knowledge about other libs. (In your case os)

Comment: If you think it is diffcult to understand, just mark this answer unuseful.It does not matter. but all I want to do is to provide help.

Comment: @NeoWu If all you want to do is help, then you can do that by making a simpler example! ;p